# Yii Query Builder nested conditions

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have Yii query builder command:

```
echo Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('table')
    ->where('a = 1')
    ->orWhere(['like', 'b', '%A%'])
    ->orWhere(['like', 'b', '%B%'])
    ->text;
```

It will produce following query:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ((a = 1) OR (b LIKE '%A%')) OR (b LIKE '%B%')`

How to write nested query to get result like:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = 1 AND (b LIKE '%A%' OR b LIKE '%B%')`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure do you want strictly this way(as u have mentioned) or not. I mean you can do this by simple string e.g

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE a = 1 AND (b LIKE '%A%' OR b LIKE '%B%')");
```

In case you want exactly your way then i am not sure bcz i have not tested the code but i think it should work. e.g

```
 ->where('a = 1',
array('and',
array("b LIKE '%A%'",
array('OR',
array("b LIKE '%B%'")))))
```

Comment: It will generate only `WHERE a = 1`.